# Remove HTML TAGS from Facebook Posts

Tags: php, html, facebook

When posting a page from the website, the html tags are showing in the post, they don't however show in the website page. does anyone know why this would be happening, and how it could be fixed?

Screenshot Attached

[image]

Comment: can you post the URL here that you are trying to share on FB ?

Comment: Have you tried [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) on that text ?

Comment: Hmmm, the `strip_tags()` function would then loose the formatting on the actual website.

Answer (score 2):

Where do you actually have the text that is displayed in the facebook post? You need to use [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) meta tags in the head of your website.

```
  <meta property="og:description" content="Your description" />
```

Within these tags you should not use any html tags. Just the text you want to display. In this case strip_tags() would do what you want and would not affect any display of text in the website since this is just a meta tag in the head section.

If you are not using Open Graph then my guess is that facebook automatically takes some text from the website and puts it as a description in the facebook post.

Comment: Yeah, this is the correct solution to the problem, when using php you can strip the tags from the variable that generates the description, (as suggested above), then place in the Open Graph meta tags.